# Electron - How to display a child window with content from a div?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I want to open a second window onclick with content from a div within the html from the first window.

I got following:

**Main.js**  | Second Window

```js
categoryWindow = new BrowserWindow ({
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      backgroundColor: '#323232',
      frame: false,
      show: false
    });

    categoryWindow.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/html/game.html'),
      protocol: 'File:',
      slashes: true
    }));

    ipcMain.on('category-window', (event, content) => {
      categoryWindow.webContents.send('category-window', content);

      categoryWindow.show();
    });
```

**Main.html** | Html that contains the div content

```html
<div class="category-ct">
  <div class="category-add">
    <button class="category-add-button" id="category-add"><p class="category-add-text">Add Category</p></button>
  </div>
  <!-- Category Add Content -->
  <div class="category-add-content" id="category-add-content">
    <p>This should be shown in second window</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works, however the whole html content gets shown. Is there a way so it loads only the content from the #category-add-content div?